# How to correctly implement Typing to proxy object in Pinia

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia

I'm using Vue3 (setup script in composition API style), Typescript and Pinia (in Option API style) and I can't figure out how to correctly type the elements in my state.
Here is an exemple of my missunderstanding:

state.ts :

```
interface myObject {
  id: number
  name: string
}
interface State {
  myFavColor: string
  objList: myObject[]
}

export const useMyStore = defineStore("myStore", {
  state: (): State => ({
    myFavColor: "orange",
    objList: objService.fetchObjList(),
  }),
  getters: {
    gimmeMyFavColor: (state): string => state.myFavColor,
    gimmeObjList: (state): myObject[] => state.objList
  },
  actions: {},
});
```

myComp.vue

```js
<script setup>
const myFavCol: string = useMyStore.gimmeMyFavColor
console.log('myFavCol', myFavCol, typeof myFavCol)
// -> 'myFavCol', orange, string


const myObjList: myObject[] = useMyStore.gimmeObjList
// Got a typing error there
console.log('myObjList', myObjList, typeof myObjList)
// -> 'myObjList', [...], Proxy(Array)
</script>
```

There I've already got an issue of typing with the gimmeObjList getter and if I use the same getter in a component waiting for a type of myObject[], there is the same issue.
The point is that strings still strings (same for others primitives) but arrays of objects become Proxy(Array) (and Objects become Proxy Objects).

I'd like to use reactivity and using toRaw() doesn't fix the typing issue (I've read a lot of docs and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69833591/how-to-set-the-type-for-the-state-object-in-pinia)/[github](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/440) posts but I maybe I missed something)

--EDIT--

Here is a concrete example of my issue.
There is a store trying to handle the Map object from the Openlayers lib.
With the code of the mapStore below:

```
import type { Map } from "ol";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

interface State {
  map: Map | null;
}

export const useMapStore = defineStore("mapStore", {
  state: (): State => ({
    map: null,
  }),
  getters: {
    storedMap: (state): Map | null => state.map
  }
});
```

I've got the following error in my IDE:

```
Type '{ on: MapEventHandler<EventsKey>; once: MapEventHandler<EventsKey>; un: MapEventHandler<void>; resizeObserver_: { ...; }; ... 67 more ...; dispose: () => void; } | null' is not assignable to type 'Map | null'.
  Type '{ on: MapEventHandler<EventsKey>; once: MapEventHandler<EventsKey>; un: MapEventHandler<void>; resizeObserver_: { ...; }; ... 67 more ...; dispose: () => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Map': renderComplete_, loaded_, boundHandleBrowserEvent_, maxTilesLoading_, and 51 more.ts(2322)
```

What we can notice is, if I remove the `Map | null` type of the answer of the getter, there is no longer any error. That's why I really don't understand how to type correctly complexe objects in the Pinia stores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use a store in `pinia` after importing it ([Use a store in pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Using-the-store)).

You need to call it with bracket.
It works fine for me like that :

`store.ts` :

```
 import { defineStore } from "pinia";

  export interface myObject {
    id: number
    name: string
  }
  interface State {
    myFavColor: string
    objList: myObject[]
  }
  
  export const useMyStore = defineStore("myStore", {
    state: (): State => ({
      myFavColor: "orange",
      objList: [{id: 1, name: "one"}, {id: 2, name: "two"}], // Sample of list which respect the interface
    }),
    getters: {
      gimmeMyFavColor: (state): string => state.myFavColor,
      gimmeObjList: (state): myObject[] => state.objList
    },
    actions: {},
  });
```

`Comp.vue` :

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useMyStore, myObject } from './store'
const myFavCol: string = useMyStore().gimmeMyFavColor
console.log('myFavCol', myFavCol, typeof myFavCol)
// -> 'myFavCol', orange, string


const myObjList: myObject[] = useMyStore().gimmeObjList
// Got a typing error there
console.log('myObjList', myObjList, typeof myObjList)
// -> 'myObjList', [...], Proxy(Array)
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Test Store</h1>
  <p>myFavCol: {{ myFavCol }}</p>
  <p>myObjList: {{ myObjList }}</p>
</template>
```

I don't get any type errors and the list is displayed correctly, so I hope it solves your problems, if not you need to add more details about what's happening wrong please.

---

EDIT

You need to/can cast your `state.map`, even if I don't see the affinity with the original problem:

`store.ts`

```
import { Map } from "ol";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

interface State {
  map: Map | null;
}

export const useMapStore = defineStore("mapStore", {
  state: (): State => ({
    map: null,
  }),
  getters: {
    storedMap: (state): Map | null => state.map as Map, // <-- HERE
  },
});
```

Comment: hmm... really strange that you ain't got no typing issue ...
I'm going to dig into my problem but I guess my exemple is too simple ! I going to try some differents scales of complexity for the nested object (myObject[]) to give you the more accurate answer possible ! By the way, thanks a lot for your answer !

Comment: Hi @ArrayConstructor
I still have the same issue that I simplified bellow:
Type '<detailled type with a lot of keys and types>' is not assignable to type '<my type>'.
Types of property '<a property>' are incompatible.
Type '<detailled type with a lot of keys and types>' is missing the following properties from type '<my type>': '<lot of properties>' and 19 more.ts(2322)

I tried with simpler objects and ain't got this issue. The fact is that I can't use stores with complex objects coming from external libs (in my case it is openlayers)

Comment: @FloCAD Can you update your questions with the actual code that isn't working, please ? So I can reproduce the error, because actually the error is only due to the lack of brackets after `useMyStore` → `useMyStore()`.

Comment: I add the exemple with the real Map object from OpenLayers and the exact error I get while using it. Thank you for your help whether you find the solution or not :)

Comment: @FloCAD Edited my answer too, tell me how it turns please.

Comment: Hi @ArrayConstructor , sorry for the late response.
I had tried the cast method before posting on SO but it seemed overkill to me and I thought there was a better way to handle complex nested objects.
I am not 100% satisfied with this syntax but if Pinia does not allow this to be handled otherwise, I think we can say that the method you specified is the best one.
Thank you for your involvement and your help in any case :)